# Retrieve mp3 file from database

Tags: c#, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve mp3 file from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521417/retrieve-mp3-file-from-database)

I need to retrieve mp3 files stored as byte[] array and show a link to the corresponding file and let the user to download it.. how can i do this??? sorry merely i don have any idea about this.. please help..

thank you.